# Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-context:jar:${org.springframework-version}

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

Please why am I getting this error in my pom.xml file

```
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-context:jar:${org.springframework-version}
```

**xml file**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You need to make sure you have a Maven property, inside a `<properties>` block that defines `org.springframework-version`. Like `<properties><org.springframework-version>4.0.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version></properties>`

Comment: Well then you need it to add it :).

Comment: I am having this error in one of the nodes >>>>  Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:${hibernate.version}

Comment: Then you now need to add the property `hibernate.version`, just like above ;).

Comment: I am trying to do this and I am getting an error >>>>   <properties>
  <hibernate.version>
  4.0.1
  </hibernate.version>
  </properties>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are seeing as `${...}` is called a [Maven property](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties):

> Maven properties are value placeholder, like properties in Ant. Their values are accessible anywhere within a POM by using the notation `${X}`, where `X` is the property.

In this case, Maven is trying to access the property `org.springframework-version` but it isn't defined, so nothing gets replaced.

You define your [own Maven properties](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html#resource-filtering-sect-user-defined) with the help of the `<properties>` section in the POM:

```
<properties>
    <org.springframework-version>4.2.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-version> <!-- wanted Spring version -->
    <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version> <!-- wanted Hibernate version -->
</properties>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

It is very likely you have not added the spring version number to your pom properties. Add this to your pom.

```
<properties>
    <org.springframework-version>4.2.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
</properties>
```

Change the version to any version of your choice for your project.